# Why am I unable to dynamically get tailwind colors from tailwind.config? (With SvelteKit)

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to set tailwind classes dynamically, but ran into an issue where colors defined in tailwind.config.cjs won't be loaded if I call them from a function. Here is a simplified example.

+page.svelte

```
<script>
    const getTeamName = () => {
        return 'team1';
    };
</script>

<div class={`bg-white text-teams-${getTeamName()}`}>Team 1</div>
<div class={`bg-white text-teams-team2`}>Team 2</div>
```

tailwind.config.cjs

```
const config = {
    content: [
        './src/**/*.{html,js,svelte,ts}',
        './node_modules/flowbite-svelte/**/*.{html,js,svelte,ts}'
    ],

    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: {
                teams: {
                    team1: '#e2012d',
                    team2: '#826818',
                }
            }
        }
    },
    plugins: [require('flowbite/plugin')],
};
```

Screenshot of result

[image: teams]

You can see team2 color is loading just fine, but team1 stays black (The color code is bright red). What's interesting is that if I set the getTeamName return value to 'team2', the color will load. It seems to have something to do with the colors having been loaded or not? Not sure if this is a sveltekit issue or tailwind issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the tailwind cannot scan the class, because the `getTeamName()` is a runtime variable

try use

```js
const getTeamName = (team) => {
    // use a switch or if..else.. statement here

    return 'text-teams-team1';
};
```

Comment: Oh you're awesome thank you that worked!! Can you explain what you mean by 'scan the class?' Just trying to get a better handle on tailwind.

Comment: @serp002 inside the tailwind config, the content is the file of the tailwind will 'scan' and check which class is used and generate output CSS file as you run `npm run dev` or `npm run build`, so not every class is output into final CSS file

Comment: A note about how tailwind works. It parses your code, looking for its tokens. So if you want dynamic, then you also need to show all the possibilities to that parser. Hence the quoted return above working. 'text-teams-team1' got parsed and thus is available. Unparsed colors are just not there.